# Removing all files with same name in different folders on S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using aws-sdk-ruby gem. With S3, CloudFront and Lambda.

Within S3 I am uploading a file into the root eg. `tshirt1.jpg`. When my Lambda function runs it creates variant sizes of this file and puts them into a structure like this:

```
100x100/ 
  --> webp/tshirt1.jpg
  --> jpg/tshirt1.jpg
500x500
  -->webp/tshirt1.jpg
  -->jpg/tshirt1.jpg
tshirt1.jpg
```

where the 100x100 is the new image size and the next folder is the type.

I know the filename that I want to delete, however, is there a way of finding all files in the bucket within any folder with that name and removing it.

```
def delete_resource
  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
  bucket = s3.bucket(settings.aws.bucket)
  bucket.delete_objects({
    delete:{
     objects: [
      {key: 'tshirt1.jpg'}
     ]
    }
   })
end
```

I would like to do something if possible like 
`{key: '*/*/tshirt1.jpg'}`

Is this possible or am I going to have to pass in all the possible folder paths?

Answer (score 0):

@Greyhounddad S3 does not maintain file hierarchy and it treats everything as an object and the only way to get object is through its key however,

If you want to automate the process of deleting files on other directories try using aws lambda you can execute lambda function on deleting file from one of your bucket and lambda will delete other files with same name from other another bucket or in your case directory.

let me know if it helped

Comment: Have you got a link to how lamda would do this?

Comment: are you aware about aws lambda or should i give reference to it as well?

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built capability to do this.

You will need to write a program that specifically does this.